# ImageMagick - Overlay one image onto many

Tags: imagemagick

I have a folder of images labelled: test.png and img000.png-img480.png

How can I overlay test.png onto every imgxxx.png individually?

Currently "magick test.png img000.png -compose over -composite result.png" works for a single .png, and I'm not sure how/if mogrify can be used for all of them.

Any help is greatly appreciated (non-imagemagick solutions would also be great!) thanks :)

Comment: Can't you just make a loop (script or else) over the `img*` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a copy of a few test files in a separate directory then change to that directory and try this:

```
magick mogrify -draw 'image Over 180,100 0,0 test.png' img*png
```

The `180,100` specifies where it will be drawn, and the `0,0` says to use the current size of `test.png`, i.e. no resizing. You can change the blend mode (i.e. `Over` here) for different effects. Get a list of available blend modes with:

```
magick identify -list compose
```

---

If you would like the results written in a different directory called `RESULTS`, use:

```
mkdir -p RESULTS
magick mogrify -path RESULTS -draw 'image SrcOver 180,100 0,0 test.png' img*png
```